# Is "library(reticulate)" needed in knitr setup chunk

Tags: python, r, r-markdown, knitr, reticulate

If I don't include the "library(reticulate)" line I cannot access the "py" object inside R chunks, but I can always access "r" object from within python chunks with or without including the line. So, is it really needed or this is a buggy behavior? I'm knitting with pdflatex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessary if all you need is the object `py` in **reticulate**, because you can create a global variable in the setup chunk, e.g.,

````
```{setup, include=FALSE}
py <- reticulate::py
```
````

If you don't do that, you'll have to `library(reticulate)` before you use `py` in subsequent R code chunks.

Comment: Yes, I can access `py` that way but, subsequent objects created in python chunks will be `NULL` when accessed in R chunks with `py$object`. If I want to use such objects I will have to use `reticulate::py$object` instead, right? So, I guess `library(reticulate)` is kind of mandatory if I don’t want to do that…